# Ragdolls randomly jumping around, moving on their own

Tags: rigging, physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

My model which is connected via the object>rigidbody>connect option is randomly flyin around, and moving without a reason... HOW DO I FIX THAT???

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VWw7ltLAiwBAxCotsokGrH2k7MuxtVK-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Often rigid bodies "fly apart" because they are in too close contact (or proximity) with one another when the simulation begins. To negate this behavior, try increasing the spacing between the bodies slightly. Also, be aware of the collision margin (and/or shape) if it applies.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.